# How to handle arrow key event in Cocoa app?

Tags: cocoa, keyboard-events

How to handle arrow key event in Cocoa app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See this code. I assumed the class is subclass of `NSView`.

```
#pragma mark    -   NSResponder

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString*   const   character   =   [theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers];
    unichar     const   code        =   [character characterAtIndex:0];
        
    switch (code) 
    {
        case NSUpArrowFunctionKey:
        {
            break;
        }
        case NSDownArrowFunctionKey:
        {
            break;
        }
        case NSLeftArrowFunctionKey:
        {
            [self navigateToPreviousImage];
            break;
        }
        case NSRightArrowFunctionKey:
        {
            [self navigateToNextImage];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

A view should be a first responder to receive events. Maybe this code will be required to support that.

```
#pragma mark    -   NSResponder
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyView
{
    return  YES;
}
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return  YES;
}
```

To use this method, the class should be subclass of `NSResponder`. See the other answer handling without subclassing NSResponder.

Comment: You also need to be a responder and be in the responder chain. Being a view that accepts first responder is a good way to fulfill this prerequisite.

Comment: The key codes have been the same since the days of yore and aren't likely to change. See [this informative article](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2007-05-22/virtual-key-codes) by Peter Hosey. The fact that they're only visible to us in a Carbon header doesn't mean much. CGEvents use them primarily, not the corresponding unicode.

Comment: @Josh OK. I understood. But I couldn't find defined key code constant values. To use it reliably, some kind of specification is required. Can I know where the official specification is?

Comment: @Eonil: please understand that I wasn't saying there was anything wrong _at all_ with your method. I just wanted to present a different one.

Comment: @Josh Oh, of course I do. I didn't know the method so I'm appreciating to you about it :) I just want to make it clear the 'key-code' stuff. If you felt some uncomfortable, sorry for my poor English :(

Comment: @Eonil: No, no fault of your English. I was just worried that _my_ written words may have sounded like criticism, and I wanted to make clear that this was not my intent. :) I'm glad to be able to share this information! I wish I knew more, or understood it better, so I could really explain it correctly.

Comment: @Eonil: Just stumbled across [a fairly recent Cocoa-dev thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/281840-high-level-toolkit-is-it-obsolete-or-not.html) which talks about the deprecation/non-deprecation of various parts of Carbon. It cleared a few things up for me; thought you might be interested. Summary is: GUI Carbon stuff is out, most everything else is still okay, documentation should reflect this but doesn't do such a good job.

Comment: @Josh It looks fine to use Carbon features absent on Cocoa :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I wanted a presented NSViewController subclass to be able to listen to arrow key events for navigation with minimal effort. Here's the best solution I've found, a slight variation of Josh Caswell's answer.

Define an event monitor (optional), can be locally in your NSViewController subclass .m

```
id keyMonitor;
```

Then start monitoring events, for example in viewDidLoad.

```
keyMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {

    unichar character = [[event characters] characterAtIndex:0];
    switch (character) {
        case NSUpArrowFunctionKey:
            NSLog(@"Up");
            break;
        case NSDownArrowFunctionKey:
            NSLog(@"Down");
            break;
        case NSLeftArrowFunctionKey:
            NSLog(@"Left");
            break;
        case NSRightArrowFunctionKey:
            NSLog(@"Right");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return event;
}];
```

To remove the monitor when not required (assuming you defined it)

```
[NSEvent removeMonitor:keyMonitor];
```

Comment: This is a very useful API for some edge cases where the responder chain doesn't do what you want.