# How to enable cmd+r to reload/refresh embedded OS X app WebView?

Tags: macos, webview, rubymotion

I am embedding a WebKit WebView in my RubyMotion OS X app.

```
@web_view = WebView.alloc.initWithFrame(NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1000, 500))
@web_view.setAutoresizingMask(NSViewMinXMargin|NSViewMaxXMargin|NSViewMinYMargin|NSViewMaxYMargin|NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable)
@web_view.setMainFrameURL('http://localhost:3000')
@mainWindow.contentView.addSubview(@web_view)
```

It seems by default, I can right click to display a menu which allows me to reload/refresh the page. However, <kbd>⌘ + R</kbd> does not work. How can I add this functionality?

Comment: You could listen to keyboard events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139751/objective-c-listen-to-keyboard-shortcuts-and-act-on-them then reload the frame's url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can reload the webpages if you add `reload' action into main menu.

```
addMenu('View') do
  item = addItemWithTitle('Show Toolbar', action: 'toggleToolbarShown:', keyEquivalent: 't')
  item.keyEquivalentModifierMask = NSCommandKeyMask|NSAlternateKeyMask
  addItemWithTitle('Customize Toolbar…', action: 'runToolbarCustomizationPalette:', keyEquivalent: '')

  # add Reload action
  addItemWithTitle('Reload', action: 'reload:', keyEquivalent: 'r')
end
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Just a note: this code sample assumes that you are using the default `menu.rb` generated by RubyMotion.