# How can i set shortcut keys to perform some action

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have multiple screens in my project, I want to open a specific screen on pressing some shortcut keys (like ctrl+AnykeyButton). So how can I do this programmatically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6140991/10927635

Comment: Do you want to press the shortcut keys programmatically or do you want to add a key equivalent to a menu item?

Comment: yes key equivalent

Comment: What is preventing you from setting the key equivalent of the menu item?