# How do you return the value of a keystroke in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am a noob at cocoa development and I am trying to make a very basic program that displays the value of any pressed key in a label and then clears when the key is unpressed. I have searched everywhere and I have found similar threads and drudged through the cryptic developer library but I can't seem to get them to work. Any help would be great. Remember I am very new.

All I really need is to know what code will return the value of the key pressed while the program is running. I can probably figure it out from there.

Thanks

edit-
Ok. I have read through the Apple documentation on the responder chain a few times and I think I get the concept. However, I don't see why my code isn't working. Here is what I have. I assume I can put this under the implementation of the App Delegate? I just have a simple default application. The NSApplication should pass the keyDown event to the app delegate and the since it is the first responder, it should read the key and log it, right? As you can tell I may not completely understand how events work yet. Any assistance would be awesome.

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{

    NSString *key = [theEvent characters];


    NSLog(@"keyDown [%@]", [theEvent characters]);
}
```

Comment: The first step would be to understand the responder chain well. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW11

Comment: See also [How to handle arrow key event in a Cocoa App?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6000133), which will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever object is the first responder needs to implement `-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent` and `-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent`. You can get the characters from the event in the form of an `NSString` with `-(NSString *)character`. If you just have a single window in your app and set its controller to implement the above methods it should work as long as you don't have something else in your window that eats the events.